# Align depth and rgb images for oni files

Tags: kinect, openni

I have an oni file where depth and rgb images are not aligned. I read in other questions that in this case it is useful to use GetAlternativeViewPointCap(). However this does not work.

I tried the following code:

`if (depth.IsCapabilitySupported(XN_CAPABILITY_ALTERNATIVE_VIEW_POINT)) {
    depth.GetAlternativeViewPointCap().SetViewPoint(image);
    }`

In the xml file I tried (one of the several attempts)

```
....
```

`<Recording file="file.oni" />
    <Node type="Depth" >
         <Query>
             <Capabilities>
             <Capability>Alternative View</Capability> 
             </Capabilities> 
         </Query>
         <Configuration>
         </Configuration>
</Node>`

....

Is it possible to use GetAlternativeViewPointCap also for already recorded files? 
How the xml file should be configured?

Based on the capabilities that I add I get the error: Open failed: The node is locked for changes!

Any idea?
Tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load a recording file you cannot change its Capabilities, Resolution, etc.
Configuring is only relates when connecting to a real hardware.